# catia : how can i make the macro : Apply powercopy to each part at once

Tags: catia

For example, there are 20 parts in a product.

I have to apply the already made 'powercopy' to each of the 20 parts.

I would like to apply this at once using macros.

Is this possible?

Comment: what have you tried? please show us your code.

Comment: The answer is "Yes, this is possible". As Yannis said, if you need help on your code, you should show us what you've done, we'll gladly help you :)